# PHP semi-random string generator

Tags: php

How to make my id generator code *elegant*: When a user registers they get an id.. What is the chance that the id generated will NOT be unique? Also - How can i make my code elegant?
THANKS!

```
#hash = random url generated from 128 chars

$cac = substr($hash, 64,-60);

$words = array('GET', 'COOL', 'WOW', 'YES', 'NICE', 'BUCK', 'LUCK', 'FUN', 'CASH', 'TIP', 'PEEK', 'TAG'); 
$rword = rand(0,11);

$syms = array('-', '#', '$', '@');
$rsym = rand(0,3); 

$nums = rand(0,9);

$aff_id_temp = $words[$rword] . $syms[$rsym] . $cac . $nums;
$final_id = strtoupper($aff_id_temp);
```

---UPDATE---
The code works. Just need to generate a simple affiliate id for users when they register. By elegant I mean – perhaps the way I am hacking out the final product code be done more simply or in a different way (perhaps in a loop) basically I want to learn different ways to achieve the same result. I want other coding perspectives.

The output is something like:  TIP#6C1D2

Comment: Define what you mean by elegant.  Be specific what the problem is.  It would also help to have some context as to what you are trying to do, and expected output.

Comment: How about: md5( $salt . $user['email'] );

Comment: Updated question.. @HappyTimeGopher  im not concerned with my $hash -> I'm more interested in **different** ways to obtain my $final_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically zero, due to the hash. That said, it depends entirely on the hash function.

Excluding the hash, the chance of any given id colliding with another given id is `1/(12*4*10) = 1/480`, roughly 0.2%. However, the chance of a new id not colliding with any other id is `1-(1-1/480)^c`, where `c` is the number of ids you already have. With just 50 ids you already have a 10% chance of collision.

You can get a unique hash with the [`uniqid`](http://php.net/uniqid) function.

Comment: My hash is being generated using a `rand`1,1B and then `hash` of SHA512  -- How does my HASH effect your equation?

Comment: Besides the `HASH` I'm more interested in the $final_id -> How else could you get to the same result. I feel like their are more "elegant" or different solutions. THANKS FOR THE HELP!